# is there a non brute force regex for matching 1st (x to y) characters of a word?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following regex which works, in PERL, to find if the start of a word is contained in a string. I want it to be okay to find, say, **divo** but not **dive**. This is not too bad with brute force.

```
if ($a =~ /\b(div|divo|divor|divorc|divorce|divorces)\b/i)
{
  print "OK, I found the substring I needed.";
}
```

In other words, if my program sees the start of "divorces" in a string, it flags that string as something I want to look at.

This is okay if I want to do this once, but I have a reason to do this multiple times with multiple words.

Is there a way to do this just with regexes, or would I have to do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $str = <STDIN>)
{
  if (mymatch($str, "divorces", 3, 8))
  {
    print "Yay!\n";
  }
}

sub mymatch
{
  my $temp;
  for ($_[2]..$_[3])
  {
    $temp = substr($_[1], 0, $_);
    if ($_[0] =~ /\b$temp\b/i)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

While being able to use a function like the above is acceptable to me, I have a feeling I'm missing a powerful advanced regex that might be helpful to me in the future as well.

Thanks for any and all help with this!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, is that [sample](https://www.debuggex.com/r/on_W3yEqk8U0DX03) what you are looking for ?

Comment: Never mind... Now I understand, what I provided is actually brute force :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you turn things inside out. Instead of

```
"divo settlement talks" =~ /\b(div|divo|divor|divorc|divorce|divorces)\b/i
```

let's do

```
"divorced" =~ /^(?:divo|settlement|talks)/i
```

Code:

```
sub mymatch {
    my ($str, $targ, $min) = @_;
    my $max = length($targ);
    for my $word (grep { length($_) >= $min && length($_) <= $max } $str =~ /\w+/g) {
        return 1 if $targ =~ /^$word/i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
sub mymatch {
    my ($str, $targ, $min) = @_;
    my $max = length($targ);
    for my $word ($str =~ /\b\w{$min,$max}\b/g) {
        return 1 if $targ =~ /^$word/i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
sub mymatch {
    my ($str, $targ, $min) = @_;
    my $max = length($targ);
    my $pat = '^(?:' . join('|', $str =~ /\b\w{$min,$max}\b/g) . ')';
    return $targ =~ /$pat/i;
}
```

---

Your way, while more complex, has the advantage of a building a regex that can search large amounts of text, and even multiple words at once.

```
sub build_pattern {
    my $min = shift;
    my @targs;
    for my $targ (@_) {
        push @targs, map { substr($targ, 0, $_) } $min..length($targ);
    }

    my $pat = join('|', @targs);
    return qr/\b(?:$pat)\b/i;
}

my $re = build_pattern(3, qw( divorced ... ));

$str =~ $re
```

Answer (score 1):

You're aware of word boundaries in your regex. So, try splitting the text into words:

```
my $text = "The case took a dive when the two parties divided over division of assets in the divorce.";

my @text_words = split(/\s+/, $text);
```

Now make a (set) hash of key words you are interested in:

```
my %key_words = map { $_ => 1 } qq(div divo divor divorc divorce divorces);
```

And look for the one in the other:

```
foreach my $word (@text_words) {
    if (exists $key_words{$word}) {
        # Your code goes here.
        print "OK, I found the substring I needed.";
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that you can merge is with other words/prefixes you might be interested in, and search for them all at the same time.